# rails different ways of defining methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been studing Rails for a not such a long time up to now .... so if there are feel free to correct me

I see that there are two ways of defining methods in rails

1. `def method_name(param)`
2. `def self.method_name(param)`

The difference (as i understand) is that 1 is mainly used in controllers while 2 is used in models... but occasionaly i bump into methods in models that're defined like 1.

Could you explain to me the main difference of thease two methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number 1. This defines a `instance method`, that can be used in instances of the model.
Number 2. This defines a `class method`, and can only be used by the class itself.
Example:

```
class Lol
  def instance_method
  end
  def self.class_method
  end
end

l = Lol.new
l.instance_method #=> This will work
l.class_method #=> This will give you an error
Lol.class_method #=> This will work
```

Answer (score 2):

The method self.method_name defines the method on the class.  Basically within the class definition think of self as referring to the class that is being defined.  So when you say def self.method_name you are defining the method on the class itself.

```
class Foo 
  def method_name(param)
     puts "Instance: #{param}"
  end

  def self.method_name(param)
     puts "Class: #{param}"
  end
end

> Foo.new.method_name("bar")
Instance: bar
> Foo.method_name("bar")
Class: bar
```